# HTML is still included when using ngIf with variable

Tags: angular, angular7

I the following Angular component:

```
export class HeaderMainComponent {
  @Input() showFullMenu: boolean = false;
}
```

Then on the HTMl I have:

```
<p>{{showFullMenu}}</p>

<nav *ngIf="showFullMenu">
  <li>Link 1</li>
  <li>Link 2</li>
</nav>
```

The variable showFullMenu is rendered as `false` but the nav still shows.

I am using the template as follows:

```
<header-main showFullMenu="false"></header-main>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure that `showFullMenu` is not set to the string `"false"` (which is truthy)?

Comment: I am defining the variable when I use the component using: <header-main showFullMenu="false"></header-main>. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Use `[showFullMenu]="false"` to evaluate the value as a boolean.

Comment: it is confusing sometimes to use with or without [] for input, so I just use <nav *ngIf="showFullMenu|cooerceToBoolean"> always :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HTML, any non-empty attribute evaluates to true. So this `showFullMenu="false"` sets the attribute to the string "false", and that will result in the boolean variable being evaluated to *true*.

To set it to *false*, you you have two options:

- Set the HTML-attribute to an empty string or omit the attribute completely
- Use the Angular syntax `[showFullMenu]="false"`. This will parse "false" as an expression which will result in a boolean value of *false*.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need @Input here if you are setting the default value and expecting it to be false, remove @Input and rest should work fine.

If you still need @Input make sure you are using `===` 'false'

With your latest edit, you should pass @input value as

```
<header-main [showFullMenu]="false"></header-main>
```